# Is windows's setsockopt broken?

Tags: python, windows, sockets, setsockopt

I want to be able to reuse some ports, and that's why I'm using **setsockopt** on my sockets, with the following code:

```
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET,socket.SO_REUSEADDR,1)
```

However, this doesn't really work. I'm not getting a bind error either, but the server socket just isn't responding (it seems to start , but if I try to connect to it, it doesn't enter the select loop). This behaviour appears if the script ended unexpectedly, and if I change the port the server is listening on, everything works again. Can you provide some advice?

EDIT: I renamed the socket to sock. It was just a name I chose for this code snippet.

Comment: you should call setsockopt on your socket, which you don't seem to do. are you sure that you're not shadowing built-in?

Comment: It's just a name I chose for this snippet.

Comment: This question should probably be renamed to "Is windows's SO_REUSEADDR  broken?"

Answer (score 3):

It appears that SO_REUSEADDR has different semantics on Windows vs Unix.

See this [msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740621(VS.85).aspx) (particularly the chart below "Using SO_EXCLUSIVEADDRUSE") and this [unix faq](http://www.developerweb.net/forum/showthread.php?t=2981).

Also, see this [python bug discussion](http://bugs.python.org/issue2550), this [twisted bug discussion](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/1151), and this list of differences [between Windows and Unix sockets](http://itamarst.org/writings/win32sockets.html).

Answer (score 1):

`setsockopt` is a method of a socket object. module `socket` doesn't have a `setsockopt` attribute.

Comment: I named my socket object in this example socket. In my code, it's name is "listening_sock"